# Why does the Kubuntu 21.10 login screen stop responding?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, login, mouse, 21.10

Occasionally, when I try to sign in on Kubuntu 21.10, the login screen will no register keypresses or mouse clicks. I can still move the cursor around the screen, but cannot interact with the password entry field or any of the onscreen buttons, e.g. shut down or reboot. The only way to get logged in at this point is to use the computer's hardware power button to turn off the machine, then power it up again with fingers crossed that the problem won't happen next time.

The computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad P15v Gen 2. This issue happens on 10-20% of login attempts.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Lenovo ThinkPad P15v Gen 2 comes with 11th gen Intel CPUs and brand new Nvidia graphics. Hopefully you selected to install additional graphics drivers during Ubuntu installation? And disabled Secure Boot in UEFI?

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes, I made sure to install the additional Nvidia drivers, and disable secure boot in UEFI.